# how to plot Multidimensional list (list of lists ) in matplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

how to plot Multidimensional list like one below using matplot

```
d=[[1 ,1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0 ,0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0 ,0 ,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0 ,0 ,1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0 ,0 ,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0 ,0 ,0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [1 ,1 ,0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0 ,0 ,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0 ,0 ,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0 ,0 ,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [1 ,0 ,1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0 ,0 ,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

i used KMeans algorithm from scikitlearn to form clusters but i need a way to visualize these clusters. 
here my code for k-means

```
cl= KMeans(n_clusters=4)
cl.fit(d)
cen = cl.cluster_centers_
lab=cl.labels_
```

i know how to use matplot to plot simple graph but i never used to Multidimensional. i want to plot d and then cluster_centers (centroids)
plot should be something like this 
[image]
is there any hit may help me accomplish this task?

Comment: what does `d` represent ?

Comment: How do you want to plot it?

Comment: sorry there was a typo , anyway it is Term Document
Matrix (TDM) which is holding frequencies of different word.

Comment: i want to plot d and then cluster_centers (centroids)

Comment: Well, one can't visualize 34D points in a 2D plot! You might want to use dimensionality reduction techniques to 2D or 3D!

Comment: @kero, please, note that if the answer solves your problem, you can 'accept' it by clicking on the check mark to the left of the answer text. This increases reputation of the author of the answer as well as yours own reputation, so benefiting both.

Comment: @Ilya V. Schurov i did already

Comment: @kero, no, you didn't. According to your user page, you didn't accept any of the answers to your questions. See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235) for details on how to accept an answer. Green checkmark should appear when you accept it.

Answer (score 2):

As @Mahdi said, you have to use some [dimensionality reduction](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/decomposition.html#decompositions) to be able to plot the points from high-dimensional space on two-dimensional screen. (Of course, you will loose some information, but that's unavoidable.) Here is an example to how to do it with [PCA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_component_analysis) (however, there are different techniques, check the references above).

```
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline

# d = ... (the same as in the question)

n_clusters = 4
cl= KMeans(n_clusters=n_clusters)
cl.fit(d)
cen = cl.cluster_centers_
lab=cl.labels_

pca = PCA(2)
# reduce dimension to 2

coords = pca.fit_transform(d)

plt.scatter(coords[:, 0], coords[:, 1], 20, c=lab, cmap='spring')
centroids_transformed = pca.transform(cen)
# transform centroids coordinate to new space

plt.scatter(centroids_transformed[:, 0], centroids_transformed[:, 1], 60,
            c=range(n_clusters), cmap='spring', marker='v')
# plot centroids. they are presented in the same order as labels,
# so colors are just range
```

[image]